# Can't play sound from an array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, audio

I'm trying to create a Drum Kit website. I use array as a placeholder to all the sound files, and use loop to call the play() function.
When I try to load, the debug consol said: "Uncaught DOMException DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found."

The problem is that if I replace "audio.src = playlist[i];" by "audio.src = playlist[1];", the website can locate the source of the file & play the selected sound. But if I replace [1] by [i], the website can't locate the source file. So why is it?

Do you know why Javascript behaves this way? I can find another way to get the website to work but this thing has been tickling in my mind for a while.

Below is my Javascript codes:

```
var audio = new Audio();

var playlist = new Array("sounds/crash.mp3","sounds/kick-bass.mp3","sounds/snare.mp3","sounds/tom-1.mp3","sounds/tom-2.mp3","sounds/tom-3.mp3","sounds/tom-4.mp3");

var drum = document.querySelectorAll(".drum")

for (var i = 0; i < drum.length; i++) {
        drum[i].addEventListener("click", play);
        function play() {
            audio.src = playlist[i];
            audio.play();       
            }
    }
```

Below is the HTML:

```
<body>

  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>
 
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the HTML it's difficult to say. But it seems like the number of items returned by `document.querySelectorAll(".drum")` is greater than the number of items in `playlist`. So eventually you run out of `playlist` items and `audio.src` is assigned the value undefined.

Comment: Good catch. OP could just put the audio location string in a data-attribute on the .drum elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have checked the HTML. They have the same number of items. I also edited and added the html.

Comment: Hey this answer is corrected. I forgot that Array starts from 0 and .length starts from 1, so there is no source for playlist[7].